# Why $X_{2n}$ when $n=3k$ has order $6$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $X_{2n}$ be the group whose presentation is$\langle x,y\,|\,x^n=y^2=1, xy=yx^2\rangle$. From $x=xy^2$, it is seen that $x^3=1$, hence $X_{2n}$ has at most $6$ elements. I have to show that if $n=3k$, then $X_{2n}$ has exactly $6$ elements.

I can't see where I am having problem if I assume $x=1$.

Comment: If $x=1$, then your group is $\langle y | y^2=1\rangle \cong C_2$

Comment: $x,y$ are generators. We cannot assume that they are $1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, but as a later comment points out, if $\gcd(3,n)=1$, then $x=1$.

Comment: Of course, in the context of $x^3=1$ we can speak of $x=1$, but not as you did.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, will you please explain? I am very confused.

Comment: In a presentation $\langle x,y\mid r(x,y)=1\rangle$ of $G$ you cannot assume $x=1$, because this is no longer the group $G$. So your last sentence does not make sense. Considering an equation $x^3=1$ in $G$, it makes sense to conclude $x=1$, for example, if you also know that $x^2=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements $x=(1,2,3)$ and $y=(2,3)$ of $S_3$ satisfy the three relations when $n=3k$, and $S_3$ has order $6$ and is generated by $x$ and $y$. So $|X_{2n}| \ge 6$ when $n=3k$.

Also, the relations can be used to write any element of $X_{2n}$ in the form $x^ay^b$,  the fact that $x^3=y^2=1$ in $X_{2n}$ proves that $|X_{2n}| \le 6$ for all $n$.

So $|X_{2n}|=6$ when $n=3k$.

Answer (score 0):

You know that $y^2=1$, to show that $x^3=1$, notice that $xyxy=x(x^2)=x^3$, also $xyxy=yx^2yx^2=yx(xyx)x=yxyx^4=x^6$, so $x^3=1$. From here on, you can show that the 6 elements are: $$1,x,x^2,y,xy,yx$$ and that multiplying either of these yields no new element.

Comment: If $n$ is not divisible by $3$, then $x=1$ and $|X_{2n}| = 2$, so you do need $n=3k$.

Comment: You're right, thank you!